# Open collector to high-z

Tags: analog, open-collector, high-impedance

Keeping it completely analog, is there a way to high-z an open collector output? An open collector always allows a path to or from a specific voltage potential and this is complicating a rather simple task for me. The only way I can think of to do this is to interject an analog switch IC into the mix, but is there a way to do this with passives? I could use a transistor but then I'd also have to add logic to control the transistor and at that point a switch IC would be just as easy. Thanks much!

Comment: Did you mean "totem pole" wherever you wrote "open collector"?

Comment: Nope. I am using voltage comparators (LM319's and LM393's) with open collector outputs (requiring a pull-up resistor).

Comment: What is your task?

Comment: I'm using the output of voltage comparators as an input to a positive-feedback latch made from another comparator. The circuit I'm following requires high-z, not just 0 volts and the open-collectors keep messing up the inputs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Open collector outputs are always hi-Z when they are high. The only way to source current from an OC output when they are high is via an external pullup.

Comment: :) Sure... but then you have unusable outputs. Wouldn't they always be high-z even if they were in their "low" state?

Comment: No, an OC output is tied to ground through its low-side transistor when low.

Comment: Wow. I hate when I learn something I should have known months ago. This could actually work for me since I don't actually need to ever drive the inputs high, just low(-5V in this case) or high-z. I'll give it a shot, but it sounds like it should work!